# LINQ error when selecting a float datatype value

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I know there are several posts on the above topic. But I'm still unclear as to why I'm getting the following error on the following `LINQ` query. **Note**: In the following query I tried `var fCost = ....` as well but still the exact same error.
**Error**: `Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'`

```
float? fCost = _context.Orders.Where(r => r.OrdID == 123).Select(t => t.cost).SingleOrDefault();
```

**Model:**

```
public class Order
{
   public int OrdID { get; set; }
   public float? cost{ get; set; }
   ....
   ....
}
```

**UPDATE**:

There was a typo in the error message above, instead of `'System.String'` it should be `'System.Single'`  The error message is as follows. This error has been there all along though:

```
Unable to cast object of type `'System.Double' to type 'System.Single'`
```

Comment: What's the error? also `SingleOrDefault` this method throws an exception if there is more than one element in the sequence.

Comment: @OrthoHomeDefense I've added the error message in the post. Also, I think error will not be the one I described if there were more than one elements in the sequence, correct?

Comment: if you change your `float? fcost` to `var fcost`, what is the value of `fcost`? ANd what about null coallesce after each step?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't get to that point since the error occurrs at that particular line `float? fCost = _context.Orders......` whether I use `float? fCost =....` or `var fCost =....`.. I am not clear on second part of your question. I've tried `....Select(t =>t.cost ?? 0).SingleOrDefault()` in the above query as well but same error

Comment: For null coallesce I mean like `_context.Orders.Where(r => r.OrdID == 123)?.Select(t => t.cost)?.SingleOrDefault();`

Comment: @Jonathan I just tried your suggestion but still the same error.

Comment: @Jonathan There was a slight typo in the error message that I've corrected in newly added **UPDATE** section in my post. But the corrected error has been there all along.

Comment: Is that exactly the query you are running? The exception you are getting comes generally when the type of data you are getting from server is not expected type. float? maps to real & double? maps to float in sql server & certain operators change the type. Check your database definition. The query being executed in logs to get more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried the following, and it succeeded. fcost1 was null, fcost2 was `1`, and fcost3 was null. So perhaps it's something in your context? The Order object is not what you think it is?

```
    private void DoWork()
    {
        var orders = BuildOrders();
        float? fCost1 = orders.Where(r => r.OrdID == 1).Select(t => t.cost).SingleOrDefault();
        float? fCost2 = orders.Where(r => r.OrdID == 2).Select(t => t.cost).SingleOrDefault();
        float? fCost3 = orders.Where(r => r.OrdID == 3).Select(t => t.cost).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    internal class Order
    {
        public int OrdID { get; set; }
        public float? cost { get; set; }
    }

    private IEnumerable<Order> BuildOrders()
    {
        return new List<Order>
        {
            new Order
            {
                OrdID = 1,
                cost = null
            },
            new Order
            {
                OrdID = 2,
                cost = 1
            }
        };
    }
```

Comment: Your example works. I need to dig deeper into my code or data.